# Laravel AJAX call using formData with files problems accessing payload

Tags: ajax, laravel

Hoping someone can help... I have a form with 5 x drag and drop JS elements on it. I am trying to use an AJAX call to upload the files to the server and not sure if the payload is working OR if it contains the real data (file name and physical file).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDsEc.png)

Above is the response in console as a result of (inside controller)
    `$input = $request->all(); $data = $request->ufiles; $s3 = $request->input('ufiles');`

If I try ->hasFile on the ufile field I get null.

The Drag and Drop code I am using is via     `https://codepen.io/incentive/details/mdwoVqO`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjzDE.png)

Above is my Ajax Call.

So based on above, I am unable to itterate through the array **{ufiles: '[object File],[object File]'}**

I am also not 100% sure the payload is including the files physically...

Can anyone see an issue above? I'd greatly appreciate being pointed in thee right direction around where I have gone wrong... Thanks in advance.

Tried using `$_FILES` (same result)
Tried hasFile, `get_file_contents` etc etc - and cannot get any values from the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the files individually to the form data object.

```
const formData = new FormData();
for (let x = 0; x < dataRefs.files.length; x++){
    formData.append(name +'[]', dataRefs.files[x]);//added [] for array in PHP
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Musa.. It is now returning what looks like a proper array - definately in the right direction. The array now displays as [[Prototype]] : Object  Is does however return TRUE when I test with hasFile... Sorry about the dumb question, but how do I itterate through this array?

Comment: `$_FILES['image_background']['tmp_name'][0]`, `$_FILES['image_background']['tmp_name'][1]` etc. Don't know how it works in lavarel though.

Comment: Thank you so much Musa - lost hours playing around with this. All working perfectly now - appreciate your assistance